# Is "a Japanese novel" written in Japanese or can it be a translation?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Mary read a Japanese novel yesterday.

Which of the following is correct?

1. The novel is written in Japanese.
2. The novel may be an English/French/etc… translation of a novel written in Japanese.

I asked this question to some Japanese who are more competent in English than I am, but none of them could answer, hence this thread.

Comment: As you say, it is ambiguous. [Japanese](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/japanese?q=Japanese) can mean the language or the country. You'll need to ask Mary for clarification.

Comment: What about "a French novel" and "a German novel"? Are they both ambiguous?

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: If a Japanese writer writes a novel about Japan but in another language, is that a ‘Japanese novel’?  I don't know.  How about Nabokov (a Russian who wrote in English): do any of his works have explicitly Russian settings or themes?

Comment: A Japanese novel does not tell us if the novel was translated into English or if she read it in Japanese. You can substitute any language there and the result is the same. That said, if speaking to English speakers, I'd say: I read a French novel in the original yesterday.

Comment: say "a novel in Japanese" if you mean the novel was written in Japanese.  Otherwise, say "an English translation of a Japanese novel" or "an English novel written by a Japanese author" if it was written originally in English by someone who is Japanese.

Comment: @AntonSherwood I've never thought of novels that a Japanese wrote in English. By the way, almost all Japanese are unable to read novels written in English.

Comment: @Kaguyahime - there are Japanese authors who write in English.  For example [Kazuo Ishiguro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazuo_Ishiguro).

Comment: Wikipedia says that Ishiguro Kazuo is a British novelist.

Comment: Yes, but he was born in Japan, and his mother and father were Japanese - so yes he has a British passport now, and obviously speaks English - but he is not a native English speaker. He moved to the UK at age 6. He is quite famous, and has a Nobel Prize for literature.

Comment: Probably, Ishiguro is an exceptional case. By the way, according to the translator of *A Pale View of Hills*, he can hardly read Japanese.

Comment: I sometimes read a Russian math history book. I don`t read Russian, but the book is still culturally Russian after translation to English!

Comment: *Madame Bovary* is a French novel, even when it has been translated into English.

Comment: As has been said 100 million times on this site, ***English is incredibly ambiguous.*** The answer to 100.00000000% of questions which contain the word "ambiguous" is simply "Yes".  the quoted sentence is highly ambiguous (I can immediately, instantly, think of at least seven meanings). There has to come a point where "Is this ambiguous" questions are just closed.

Comment: "Wikipedia says that Ishiguro Kazuo is a British novelist" As always, "Wikipedia is a joke"

Comment: @BillyKerr. RE <say "a novel in Japanese">. Can we say "Akiko read a German novel in Japanese yesterday"? If so, is "in Japanese" adjectival or adverbial?

Comment: @Kaguyahime - well you can say it (it's not ungrammatical), but it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Kaguyahime - I wouldn't be so sure that Ishiguro is an exceptional case. There are probably quite a few people of Japanese origin living in western countries who can read, write and speak very good English.  Most English speaking countries like the UK, US, Canada, Australia, and NZ are very cosmopolitan societies with people of many different nationalities from all over the world.

Comment: @BillyKerr - I googled, but I found only two novels written by a Japanese writer in English.

Comment: @BillyKerr Ishiguro doesn't just "speak very good English", he's been a British citizen for 40 years and according to Wikipedia, is on the record distancing himself from other Japanese fiction. I do think it makes calling his novels or him Japanese a little more complicated (and potentially problematic).

Comment: It's definitely ambiguous. With translated works it's very common: you'd say "I read a French novel" if reading Sagan or Robbe-Grillet in translation, and reading an untranslated book by Georges Simenon (who was Belgian but wrote in French). But if someone who wasn't French or from a French-speaking country wrote in French (like Samuel Beckett), you might call them "plays in French" rather than "French plays". While someone like Kafka is contested, so it can be political whether you call them "German literature" or "Jewish/Czech literature in German".

Comment: If you are speaking English and your interlocutor and you not speak Japanese, "I read a Japanese novel" would have to be a translation...

Answer (score 26):

It is ambiguous and could mean many different things:

1. It was written in Japanese and may or may not have been translated to another language
2. It was written/published in Japan (in any language)
3. It was written by a Japanese person (in any language from any location)
4. It discusses issues related to Japan or Japanese people

The most likely is (1), but you will either need to infer from context or ask for clarification.

Comment: Upvoted because I agree with 1,2,3; but I think 4 would be "a book on Japan" or "a book about Japan" or "a book on Japanese culture" or informally "a Japan book", but not "a Japanese book".

Comment: @Stef Re. 4: yes, you'd probably use another expression for that, as you illustrate — but not certainly.  For a similar example, with no other context, ‘a Japanese guidebook’ would be a guidebook for visitors to Japan, not necessarily by a Japanese person, nor in Japanese, nor written or published in Japan.

Comment: It could also be a novel about Japanese (the language)

Comment: Yeah context matters the most. First thing that comes to mind is "is Mary learning Japanese?"

Comment: Regarding 4, it's less common, but I'd certainly call a book about Japanese history "a Japanese history book", which is ambiguous. And if someone lived in Japan for a year and later wrote a book about it, you could call it "their Japanese book" even if they were American and wrote it in English in New York - even a work of poetry in a Japanese style might be called "the Japanese book/poetry" at least to distinguish it from other books/poetry they wrote. Context is all.

Comment: I find the specific use of "novel" a bit interesting, as that may refer to the non-physical arrangement of prose itself, which is closely linked to the form in which it was originally written. Great Expectations is a Victorian novel because the prose - the novel itself - was written in Victorian times. A copy printed in 2024 might be a modern *book*, but it's not a modern *novel*. Without further specification, I'd usually take "novel" to refer to the intellectual content and story rather than the particular form it takes. I'd say a Japanese novel remains Japanese when translated.

Comment: It could also mean that the novel follows some kind of style that is prevalent in Japanese literature

Comment: Although unlikely I think it could also be just any novel that has been translated to Japanese. As in "this person can read Japanese because they read a Japanese translation of novel X".

Answer (score 9):

Language is vague.  "Japanese novel" normally means a novel written in Japanese (there is no requirement for it to be written by a Japanese person, lots of English novels are written by people who aren't English)

But I've read "Face of Another" (他人の顔) I read it in English.  Did I read Abe Kobo's book?  Yes. Is his book a Japanese novel?  Yes.  Did I read a Japanese novel?  Errr... Yes, in some sense. If someone asked me if I've ever read a Japanese novel, I could answer "Yes, but only in translation."

Language is vague on this point. But don't worry since there is unlikely to be much doubt about the particular meaning, and there are lots of ways to resolve any ambiguity.  If Mary is a random English person, then the probability that she reads Japanese well enough to read novels is pretty low. But if you know that Mary has been living in Tokyo and studying Japanese for five years, then the context changes.

What about "American novels" - Probably written in (American) English, and so they are mostly also English novels. But some American novels are written in Spanish. What about Welsh novels.  It's hard to tell without context. Is this a novel with a distinctive Welsh setting?  A novel by a Welsh author? A novel written in Welsh (even though the author is Argentinian-Welsh)

Comment: In most English-speaking countries, I am sure the first thing the other person would say is 'What, in the original Japanese?'.

Comment: @James K Interesting. In Japanese, the ambiguities you mentioned are very unlikely to happen. Thanks, James.

Comment: That's partly because you have different words for "Japanese (language)" and "Japanese person"  But could not a novel written by a Japanese citizen in Ainu  not be called a Japanese novel?  What about Felipe Smith's Manga https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peepo_Choo

Comment: I was going to mention 'American' since there is no language by that name (but a dialect of English).

Comment: @JamesK There is no set orthography for the Ainu language. I would probably refer to Peepo Choo by using many words if I had to.

Comment: @Kaguyahime There functionally is a set orthography for Ainu (actually two), it’s just _de facto_ and not _de jure_. But that doesn’t really matter, because the orthography does not change the underlying language. It’s no different from how transliterating 富士山 as ‘Fujisan’ or ‘Huzisan’ does not change the fact that it is Japanese.

Comment: Ainu is a language without its own script. Ainu is a completely different language from Japanese.

Comment: English is a language with out its own script... (we use the Latin script)

Comment: Only in the Meiji period, when education in Japanese and other assimilation policies were promoted, did the Ainu begin to use letters.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - Hokkaido Government says that there is no set orthography for the Ainu language. By the way, almost all Ainu people are unable to speak Ainu.

Comment: @Kaguyahime The reality is that there are two functionally standard orthographies, one using modified katakana, and one using the Latin alphabet. The pool of people publishing written works in Ainu is so small that there is essentially zero variance in the usage of either orthography, which means they are by definition standard in practice, whether the government wants to acknowledge it or not.

Comment: @Kaguyahime Also, if you want to be that picky that ‘Ainu does not have it’s own script’ then neither does Japanese, kanji are just a borrowing of hànzì, and katakana, hiragana, and the various other historical kana are all derivatives of either kanji or hànzì. None of them originated with Japanese, just like neither of the orthographies actually in use for Ainu originated with Ainu.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - Some people doubt that kataka letters are derived from kanji. ユ is said to be derived from 由. ソ is said to be derived from 曽. but these are only guesses.

Comment: When you use the two terms together, there is no way you can say that an “American novel” is also an “English novel”. Because the word “American” (alone) is not a language, when you later use “English” the inference is you are referring to nationalities, not language. To me (native BrEng) the statement “_Catcher in the Rye_ is an English novel.“ is simply false, and there’s no way I can read it that prevents it being false.

Comment: If you are speaking English and your interlocutor and you not speak Japanese, "I read a Japanese novel" would have to be a translation...

Answer (score 4):

English is not my native language, which means that I have the advantage of actually being taught these things.

This is according to my teacher some decades ago, he generally taught us British English.

"a Japanese novel" was originally written in Japanese. It may have been translated to another language.

"a novel in Japanese" is *currently* written in Japanese, it may have been translated into Japanese.

"a Japanese novel in Japanese" is possible, but usually given as "a novel in the original Japanese".

Other meanings should be stated explicitly:  "a novel by a Japanese author", "a novel about Japan",  "a novel set in Japan" etc.

Of course, my teacher may have been teaching me a standard that nobody follows...

Comment: But it depends on how likely people are to be confused, e.g. Wilbur Smith's [Egyptian series](https://www.amazon.co.uk/River-God-Egyptian-1-Egypt-ebook/dp/B07892NCSF/) is a series of novels written in English about ancient Egypt, not in any variety of Egyptian, ancient or modern dialect. Because nobody writes in ancient Egyptian and the modern dialect is more commonly called Egyptian Arabic or Colloquial Egyptian.

Comment: If you want to be really clear that it's written in Japanese, it would be "A Japanese-language novel".

Comment: "I have the advantage of actually being taught these things" - sorry, but English is governed by 'real world' usage, so 'knowing the rules' is often a distraction. You even note yourself that you were taught British English, rather than US English or Indian English, both of which are close to being separate languages.

Comment: If you are speaking English and your interlocutor and you not speak Japanese, "I read a Japanese novel" would have to be a translation...

Answer (score 1):

### It is ambiguous. Readers will assume it is a translation, unless we have been told that Mary can read Japanese

Strictly speaking, there is not enough definite information to say what language the book is written in. However, for me, a native speaker of British English, the answer is (2): the novel originated in Japan, but is most likely a translation.

“Japanse novel” alone does not automatically mean that the text of the novel is in the Japanese language. It does strongly suggest that the novel was *originally* written in the Japanese language, but in this sentence, the better assumption is that it is a translation of that original text.

The reason for this is partly grammatical, but also semantic. First, the grammar: “Japanese” is an adjective here, and means nothing more than “belonging to or relating to Japan, its people, or its language”.  So, replacing the word “Japanese” with its definition, we get:

- A novel belonging to or relating to Japan, its people, or its language

This does still allow the meaning “written in Japanese”, but to explain why it does not in this case, we have to leave the world of grammar and look at what else the sentence is telling us.

#### Forming assumptions

The sentence:

- Mary read a Japanese novel yesterday

gives us no definite information about the language the book was
written in, but it does give us a clue: the use of the European name
“Mary” is what tips the balance to the decision that the book is not
in Japanese. Why? Because a randomly-chosen woman named “Mary” is unlikely to be fluent in Japanese, so it’s a safe assumption to make that the book is not in Japanese, unless we learn otherwise.

But it’s important to note that as the reader, I am guessing here, and that the sentence still did not tell me anything definitive about the language of the book: for all I know, Mary is a professor of Modern Japanese Literature at the local university. But until I learn differently, it’s a safe assumption to make.

To see how this kind of assumption works, consider a slightly different, but grammatically identical sentence:

- Tsumugi read a Japanese novel yesterday.

Now the word “Japanese” strongly suggests that the novel is also *written* in Japanese, and all we did was change the name of the reader! But the reasoning is the same: how likely is it that a randomly-chosen woman named Tsumugi can read Japanese? Very likely. So, once you recognise that Tsumugi is a Japanese name, it’s safer to assume that the book was in Japanese.

But again, this is just as much an assumption as before. If we limit our reasoning to what we *know* from the two sentences, it’s entirely possible that Tsumugi and Mary are sisters, they live in Africa, and that both of them speak only French.

Guiding your reader into assumptions like this is a useful technique if you are writing mystery stories, but it’s not a good idea in other kinds of writing.  It is better to be unambiguous.

#### How to be clear

If you want to unambiguously say that the text of the book is in Japanese:

- Mary read a novel in Japanese  *[common usage]*
- Mary read a Japanese-language novel  *[more formal or technical usage]*

To draw attention to the fact that the book was in Japanese, rather than in translation:

- Mary read *Snow Country* in the original Japanese yesterday

### P.S.

“Yesterday” also makes this sentence sound unusual. The word “novel” applies only to long stories, usually of over 75,000 words, but the combination of “read” (past perfect) and “yesterday” in this sentence implies that Mary completed the book, from start to finish, in one day. That’s not impossible by any means, but it isn’t something that would be casually stated in this way.

Comment: If you are speaking English and your interlocutor and you not speak Japanese, "I read a Japanese novel" would have to be a translation...

Comment: @Lambie - I agree, and that’s the basic argument I make in my answer: the most likely reading of “Japanese” as an adjective here is “of Japan”, unless the context _very strongly_ implies “in the Japanese language” - and the only thing that can provide this context in the OP’s sentence is the given-name of the reader.

Answer (score -1):

1. **Mary read a Japanese novel yesterday.**

**Does Mary read Japanese?** Yes or No? **Yes. Therefore, she read it in Japanese.**

2. Mary read a Japanese novel yesterday.

**Does Mary read Japanese?** Yes or No? **No.** **Therefore, she read it in translation.**

FOR THE RECORD: this is not a question about the English language. It would be true of any languages with adjectives similar to how they work in English.

It's quite simple really in terms of no other context.